# Generate unstructured surface mesh from coordinates

Tags: python, mesh, surface, finite-element-analysis

## Problem summary

I have a rectangular prism like in the image below where I know the coordinates of the vertices.

[image]

I want to discretize the lateral faces of the prism into an unstructured surface mesh using quadrilateral elements with a certain objective side length. More precisely, I am not interested in saving the mesh to a file, but I want a list representing the elements of the mesh and including a reference to the nodes composing each element (both in terms of id and coordinates). Is there a python library that can do this?

## Why an unstructured mesh?

For a perfect rectangular prism like the one in the image above, it is fairly simple to obtain a structured surface mesh just by playing with the coordinates and `numpy.linspace`. However, I want to be able to mesh a prism with some taper or with different bases. In those cases, a structured mesh might lead to very skewed elements, while I would like the elements to be as close as possible to a square with side equal to the objective length.

## Starting point

Ideally, the python script would start with the definition of the coordinates of the vertices and of the faces that have to be meshed:

```
import numpy as np
# Geometric properties
aspect_ratio = 9.
c = 1e3 # [mm]
b = aspect_ratio*c
non_dimensional_height = 0.1
h = c*non_dimensional_height # [mm]
non_dimensional_thickness = 0.001
t = c*non_dimensional_thickness # [mm]
# Objective length of the side of the quadrilateral elements
side_length = 10 # [mm]
# Define points coordinates
points_xyz = np.array([(0., 0., h/2),   # 0 -> A
                       (c, 0., h/2),    # 1 -> B
                       (0., 0., -h/2),  # 2 -> C
                       (c, 0., -h/2),   # 3 -> D
                       (0., b, h/2),    # 4 -> A'
                       (c, b, h/2),     # 5 -> B'
                       (0., b, -h/2),   # 6 -> C'
                       (c, b, -h/2)])   # 7 -> D'
# Define faces by sequence of points
faces = np.array([(0,1,5,4), (1,2,6,5), (2,3,7,6), (3,0,4,7)])
```

and then it would continue with the discretization of the faces and returning a list with all the elements of the unstructured mesh, where each element has a reference to its nodes (both in terms of ids and coordinates).

I have seen that there are libraries like `pyvista` and `gmsh`, but I got the impression that they are more oriented towards working with meshes imported from files rather than actually produce a mesh and the mesh connectivity information from some coordinates like I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyvista` can also be used to generate meshes using [`Polydata()`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyData.html):

> Dataset consisting of surface geometry (e.g. vertices, lines, and
> polygons).
>
> Can be initialized in several ways:
>
> - Create an empty mesh
> - Initialize from a vtk.vtkPolyData
> - Using vertices
> - Using vertices and faces
> - From a file

There are also some helper functions for simple geometric objects, e.g. [`Box`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/utilities/_autosummary/pyvista.Box.html) (it uses quadrilateral elements by default):

```
import pyvista
mesh = pyvista.Box((0, c, 0, b, -h/2, h/2), level=10, quads=True)

print(mesh)
#PolyData (0x197125e5f40)
#  N Cells: 726
#  N Points:    728
#  X Bounds:    0.000e+00, 1.000e+03
#  Y Bounds:    0.000e+00, 9.000e+03
#  Z Bounds:    -5.000e+01, 5.000e+01
#  N Arrays:    0

for i in range(mesh.number_of_cells):
    print(mesh.cell_points(i))
#[[  0.           0.         -50.        ]
# [  0.           0.         -40.90909195]
# [  0.         818.18182373 -40.90909195]
# [  0.         818.18182373 -50.        ]]
# ...
```

You can cast `PolyData` to `UnstructuredGrid` using [`cast_to_unstructured_grid`](https://docs.pyvista.org/api/core/_autosummary/pyvista.PolyData.cast_to_unstructured_grid.html).

For more information see the [Data Model](https://docs.pyvista.org/user-guide/data_model.html) section of the user guide.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a great functionality! Just one question: as far as I can see in the documentation, `Box` creates a solid mesh rather than a surface mesh, am I correct? Is there a corresponding method to create a surface mesh? Furthermore, how does `level` control the discretization of the mesh? It's not crystal clear from the docs

Comment: Yes, `Box` creates a solid mesh, you can extract its surface using [`extract_surface`](https://docs.pyvista.org/examples/01-filter/extract-surface.html). `level` subdivides each dimension of the box (width, length, height) into `level + 1` cells. You can visualize the effect by `mesh.plot(show_edges=True)`. Unfortunately, you can't specify different levels for the individual dimensions.

Comment: What do you mean by solid mesh?  `PolyData` meshes only define polygonal type cells, which fill areas in 2D.  A closed surface may define a volume that it encloses.
`UnstructuredGrid` meshes can fill areas in 3D with the cells themselves.  Note that using `extract_surface` returns another `PolyData` mesh.

Comment: @MatthewFlamm: thanks for the clarification. Solid was just the term used in fma's comment.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I meant to point this question to @fma.  Maybe they meant having solid faces, or solid volume.

Comment: Can pyvista.PolyData() help with [Generate a mesh from my polygon geometry to iterate FEM for geometry optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78055800/3904031) I'm completely new to this.